# Qt virtual keyboard deault layout is different

Tags: qtvirtualkeyboard

When i run QT virtual keyboard on my device layout is this

[image: layout on device]

but on QT website default layout for keyboard is like this

[image: qt website layout]

Why it is two default are different ? and how can i have second layout instead of first ?

Comment: The one on your device is the native one provided by the OS.

Comment: @TimRoberts not true; the Qt virtual keyboards are completely self contained, they don't rely on the OS for anything.

Comment: The keyboard layout is controlled by a layout QML file.  But as @StephenQuan points out, each language (locale) has its own layout file - the keyboards for each language need not look anything like each other.  The reversal of the Y and Z keys for example is quite common.

Comment: You're using a different language keyboard with a different layout (QWERTZ if I recall). Why do you _expect_ it to look the same as a different layout (QWERTY)?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT/REWRITE]

There are two things I wanted to cover in this answer:

1. Switching between British English (en_GB) and Slovenčina (sl_SL) keyboards can be done via setting `VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale`
2. Changing keyboard layouts can be done by setting the `QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH` environment variable

The reference documentation appears to show the keyboard in British English and using the older Qt5.15.x keyboard layouts.

```
// main.qml
Component.onCompleted: VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "en_GB"
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
qputenv("QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH", "C:/Qt/Qt5.15.6/5.15.6/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/layouts");
```

N.B. On my computer I had both Qt6.6.1 and Qt5.15.6 installed so I did the above to my `main.cpp` so that I can test the keyboard switch. To do it properly, you would need to move the keyboard layouts into your application resources and update `QT_VIRTALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH` to match.

Here's a minimum application:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout
        width: parent.width
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "en_GB"
                checkable: true
                checked: VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale === "en_GB";
                onClicked: {
                    VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "en_GB";
                    textEdit.forceActiveFocus();
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "sl_SL"
                checkable: true
                checked: VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale === "sl_SL";
                onClicked: {
                    VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "sl_SL";
                    textEdit.forceActiveFocus();
                }
            }
        }
        Frame {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            TextEdit {
                id: textEdit
                width: parent.width
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Submit")
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "en_GB";
        textEdit.forceActiveFocus();
    }
    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        y: active ? parent.height - height : parent.height
        width: parent.width
    }
}
```

Here's a screengrab using Qt6.x keyboard layouts:

[image: KeyboardApp.gif]

Here's a screengrab using Qt5.15.6 keyboard layouts:

[image: KeyboardApp2.gif]

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-settings-virtualkeyboardsettings.html#locale-prop
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtvirtualkeyboard-layouts.html
- https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/technical-guide.html#adding-custom-layouts
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/93279/how-to-custom-qml-virtual-keyboard/2

Comment: sorry for confusion because of language screen shot . Even if with British english the layout on the device is same . i.e Enter key in the bottom line . I would like Qt website layout i.e kanguage selection and keyboard hide button in the bottom line . Device keyboard layout is quite complex with setting button with comma button in the bottom line .

Comment: @user2739186 updated the answer to reflect that the keyboard layouts have been updated in the exact manner you described. It's not a bug. It's merely the latter versions of Qt have a different keyboard layout than earlier versions of Qt. If you desire the earlier version you can, but, you will have to follow additional steps (I've described and linked those steps in the answer).