# Customizing the InputPanel style in Qt6 or restoring the Qt5 one

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

Starting from Qt6, seems that the new InputPanel style "hides" the *hide keyboard* button under the *settings* one.

[image: Hide keyboard button "hidden" in Qt6]

There is a way to restore back the old Qt5 InputPanel layout or someone can explain how I can customize/create a new InputPanel style to replicate the old one?

[image: Hide keyboard button always visible in Qt5]

I know that exists a KeyboardStyle type but I cannot understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both Qt6 and Qt5 installed, say, Qt5.15.6 with sources, then you can quickly test Qt5 keyboard layouts in your Qt6 app by adding the following to your `main.cpp`:

```cpp
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
qputenv("QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH", "C:/Qt/Qt5.15.6/5.15.6/Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/layouts");
```

Next, copy the `Src/qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/layouts` to a `qt5layouts` subfolder. Next add the keyboard locales you need. Here `en_US` and `fallback` files are added to `main.qrc`:

```xml
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/dialpad.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/digits.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/handwriting.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/main.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/numbers.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/en_US/symbols.fallback</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/dialpad.qml</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/digits.qml</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/handwriting.qml</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/main.qml</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/numbers.qml</file>
<file>qt5layouts/fallback/symbols.qml</file>
```

Finally update `main.cpp` to point to the `qt5layouts` resources.

```cpp
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    qputenv("QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_LAYOUT_PATH", QByteArray(":/qt5layouts"));
```

A full working example can be found in my github repo: https://github.com/stephenquan/QtInputPanelDemo

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/technical-guide.html#adding-custom-layouts
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/93279/how-to-custom-qml-virtual-keyboard/2
- [Qt virtual keyboard deault layout is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830031/qt-virtual-keyboard-deault-layout-is-different/77830084#77830084)